# Mule 4 - Mock Oracle database insert using H2 in memory database how to override "to_date"

Tags: mule, h2, mulesoft, mule4, munit

Am trying to write Munit for a simple Database insert operation. Mule is 4.4 and using Oracle database.
However the database insert is using `to_date`

```
insert into emp_owner.emp (emp_id,start_date ) 
values (:empId,to_date(:startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

In My Munit I am using `MUnit Db Server Config` and am using H2 in memory database to mock while unit testing

Here is the flow which I want to test:

```
<db:config name="Emp_Database_Config" doc:name="Database Config" doc:id="e9ad13a0-c3bd-4f08-a384-88c027344c83" >
    <db:oracle-connection 
        host="${emp.host}" 
        port="${emp.port}" 
        serviceName="${emp.serviceName}" 
        user="${emp.user}" 
        password="${emp.password}">
        <reconnection failsDeployment="true" >
            <reconnect />
        </reconnection>
        <db:pooling-profile maxPoolSize="7"/>
    </db:oracle-connection>
</db:config>

<sub-flow name="empSub_Flow" doc:id="ed349aec-45fb-43a5-9182-97613f666a78" >
    
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Start" doc:id="7603db9c-6322-47f3-8816-cece900b18e6" message="start"/>
    

<db:insert doc:name="Insert emp data" doc:id="626a7405-0afb-40c9-bfdc-c1732c9dc61d" config-ref="${emp.dbName}">
            <db:sql><![CDATA[insert into emp_owner.emp (emp_id,start_date ) 
values (:empId,to_date(:startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))]]></db:sql>
            <db:input-parameters><![CDATA[#[{
   'empId' : payload.empId, 
   'startDate' : payload.start_date
}]]]></db:input-parameters>
        </db:insert>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="End" doc:id="0fd5c833-810e-4389-944d-b027403b5833" message="End"/>
        
    </sub-flow>
```

Here is the code for munit :

```
<munit:config name="emp-test-suite.xml" />
    
    
    <dbserver:config name="MUnit_DB_Server_Config_Emp" doc:name="MUnit DB Server Config" doc:id="96f4b81b-524f-4e4c-96a8-e9d71fda7a5a" >
        <dbserver:connection csv="emp_owner.csv" database="DATABASE_EMP" connectionStringParameters="MODE=Oracle" />
    </dbserver:config>
    
    <db:config name="Emp_Database_Config_Test">
        <db:generic-connection url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:DATABASE_EMP" driverClassName="org.h2.Driver" />
    </db:config>
    

    
    
    
    <munit:before-test name="emp-test-suiteBefore_Test" doc:id="11f4f175-6654-4b25-8957-8e8cf4c7e3f6" >
        <dbserver:execute doc:name="Execute" doc:id="f71d8154-5c1c-45f4-a73a-12212b03ea5f" config-ref="MUnit_DB_Server_Config_Emp" sql='#["CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS emp_owner; SET SCHEMA emp_owner; "]'/>
    </munit:before-test>
    <munit:test name="emp-test-suite-empSub_FlowTest" doc:id="2e7fb1c2-1548-4d2b-a902-e9c15777a944" description="Test">
        <munit:behavior >
            <dbserver:execute doc:name="Create Emp table" doc:id="4b60d5b7-5a39-40d8-a65b-582115bc7dcd" 
                config-ref="MUnit_DB_Server_Config_Emp" sql="CREATE TABLE EMP ( Emp_Id NUMBER  NOT NULL , START_DATE TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL  ) " />
        </munit:behavior>
        <munit:execution >
            <flow-ref doc:name="Flow-ref to empSub_Flow" doc:id="61b55b0b-2351-49f1-b69a-d65fe40e3241" name="empSub_Flow"/>
        </munit:execution>
        <munit:validation >
            <dbserver:execute-query doc:name="Execute query" doc:id="0338ef43-4dc1-4823-b8d6-0160d1b5598d" config-ref="MUnit_DB_Server_Config_Emp" sql='#["select * from emp_owner.emp where emp_id = 10"]' />
            <munit-tools:assert-equals doc:name="Assert equals" doc:id="f1abc645-1730-4cc2-beef-9fed6b7690ca" actual="#[!isEmpty(payload)]" expected="#[true]" message="We should see data returned from database" />
        </munit:validation>
    </munit:test>
```

while running munit  Oracle database is getting mocked with H2 , however the problem is with `to_date` function in Oracle which is not supported in H2.

Did do a google search as well as within SO and found solutions related to `alias` :

> drop ALIAS if exists TO_DATE;
>
> CREATE ALIAS TO_DATE as '
> import java.text.*;
> @CODE java.util.Date
> toDate(String s, String dateFormat) throws Exception {
> if("YYYY-MM-DD".equals(dateFormat))   {
> dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" ;
> }
> if("DD/MON/YY".equals(dateFormat))   {
> dateFormat = "dd/MMM/YY" ;
> }
>
> return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(s);
> }
> ';

However I am not sure in case of Mule how I can include in My Munit config and use it ?

Comment: This is not a question about MUnit. You are not mocking the database query. You are actually executing it, right? So this is really a question about how to execute an Oracle DB SQL query in the H2 DB.

Answer (score 0):

`TO_DATE` function is supported by H2 in the Oracle compatibility mode, you need to add `;MODE=Oracle` to JDBC URL.

Comment: thanks , do you mean this way  <db:generic-connection url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:DATABASE_EMP;MODE=Oracle" driverClassName="org.h2.Driver" />

Comment: Yes, I do. You can add settings after database name in URL, H2 uses `;` as a separator between them.

Comment: unfortunately still get this exception `"Function "TO_DATE" not found; SQL statement:
insert into emp_owner.emp (emp_id,start_date ) 
values (?,to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) [90022-200]"`

Comment: i looked at documentation - https://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility does not mention about supporting to_date

Comment: Mode-specific functions aren't documented. In old unsupported H2 1.4.200 (error code ends with 200) this function is available in all compatibility modes and this command doesn't throw any exceptions. What exactly do you use as a database server?

Comment: I was using a mevn dependency verion of 1.4.200 , so then based on your comment upgraded to 2.2.224 , however after this am getting the error `"Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:DATABASE_NAME;MODE=Oracle : Version mismatch, driver version is "0" but server version is "11" [90047-224]"`

Comment: i think this error after upgrading the h2 version seems to be related to Mule which is internally using older version of h2 ?

Comment: Version 11 is used by H2 1.3.163–1.3.167, these versions were released in 2011–2012. They don't support this function at all.